# Structuring a framework in Perl

Tags: perl, frameworks

I am writing a framework in perl in which new functionality is being added day by day. Now, instead of writing a new subroutine in a file every time there is some addition to the functionality I want a file should be created and placed in a folder and that file is called by main program. I need help how we do this? Here is my folder structure:

```
Framework
  - PerformOperation
    - Operation1.pm
    - Operation2.pm
    - Operation3.pm
  - Execute.pl
```

The `PerformOperation` folder has all the Operations/functionality which is adding day by day and Execute.pl is the main Perl file which is executed to start the framework. Now, I don't know how this can be managed.

More Info: From Execute.pl a file is read in which it is written which operations I need to perform and that particular operation is selected from `PerformOperation` and executed. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want a subroutine from Operation1.pm, you just `use PerformOperation::Operation1;`; make Operation1.pm use the Exporter module, and make sure the subname is in the `@EXPORT` array. Does that get at what you want? If not, please explain.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically load one of `Operation1.pm`, `Operation2.pm` or `Operation3.pm`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd benefit from looking at another framework to get ideas.
The Catalyst Framework does this exact thing and might offer some good insights on how to manage dynamically included modules.